# Elements and positioning not applying

Tags: html, css

I am working out of "HTML5 and CSS5 Illustrated Complete" Second Edition by Sasha Vodnik.
I did the initial Unit D example to a Tee, however logo styling and the positioning aren't applying correctly or at all.

```css
/* 
   Lakeland Reeds Bed and Breakfast style sheet 
   Filename: styles.css

   Author:  
   Date:    
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit D, Lessons
 */

/* reset styles */
article, body, div, footer, header, h1, h2, p {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* body and page container */
.container {
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: beige;
    position: relative;
    top: 6.2em;
}

/* headings */
header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 640px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    /*z-index: -1*/
}
h1 {
    padding: 0.4em;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
}

p.logo {
    padding: 0.2em;
    border: 2px solid beige;
    color: goldenrod;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 2em;
}

/* main content */
article {
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
    top: 6.2em;
}

article p {
    padding: 0 1em 1em;
}

/* sidebar */
aside {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 1em 0;
    background-color: goldenrod;
}

aside p {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    padding:  0.4em 0;
    margin: 0 0.6em;
}

/* footer section */
footer {
    padding: 0.6em;
    color: white;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    text-align: center;
    clear: right;
}
footer p {
    margin:  0.4em;
}

footer p.accent {
    color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Lakeland Reeds Bed &amp; Breakfast - Test Page</title>
      <!-- 
         Lakeland Reeds Bed & Breakfast test page
         Filename: longpage.html

         Author:  
         Date:    
         HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit D, Lessons
      -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script src="modernizr.custom.62074.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <header>
            <h1>Lakeland Reeds<br>Bed &amp; Breakfast</h1>
            <p class=”logo”>&#8466;&#8475;</p>
         </header>
         <article>
            <h2>Test Page</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam viverra ullamcorper ultrices. Morbi egestas elementum ligula, eget congue elit pulvinar placerat. Curabitur dictum, velit et iaculis mattis, felis ante sodales lectus, consectetur convallis enim urna ut libero. Suspendisse placerat dignissim quam, et consequat ligula. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur id dolor ut nulla sodales lobortis in ac dolor. Maecenas bibendum eleifend lacus, maximus dignissim mi fermentum quis. Suspendisse sagittis tincidunt pellentesque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla nunc velit, molestie nec metus vel, dictum rutrum est. Aliquam volutpat ex massa, tempus eleifend nisl eleifend sed. Fusce egestas cursus felis in fermentum. Mauris facilisis feugiat pellentesque. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec feugiat erat nec sapien tincidunt congue. Etiam urna libero, aliquet ut neque a, vulputate fermentum velit.</p>
            <p>Nullam vel enim luctus, imperdiet neque et, aliquet turpis. Morbi a rhoncus metus. Nulla facilisi. Nunc tincidunt vel eros id laoreet. Fusce id nibh rhoncus, porta nulla nec, euismod ligula. Phasellus bibendum mi lectus. Donec a egestas mauris.</p>
            <p>Curabitur et sapien consequat, varius diam in, viverra massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum facilisis urna elit, vel malesuada mauris pulvinar vitae. In ultrices tortor nisl, et faucibus ex dignissim non. Vivamus eget risus tempus, rutrum ipsum sit amet, gravida mi. Vestibulum et lobortis sem. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
            <p>Donec ultricies risus quis metus cursus, in feugiat quam ultricies. Nullam sit amet enim in tellus molestie sodales et et leo. Duis pulvinar venenatis consequat. Aenean facilisis arcu libero, a auctor odio feugiat at. Donec sagittis sollicitudin maximus. Maecenas elementum, lectus vitae fringilla tempus, mi nibh faucibus sapien, in fermentum dui massa vel dui. Nullam sed ligula scelerisque, viverra quam sit amet, bibendum libero. Duis at fermentum dolor. Phasellus non dictum nulla. Morbi a semper nibh. Vivamus ullamcorper purus ac nisi consectetur bibendum. Nulla varius sodales tempor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur imperdiet neque nec purus pellentesque, vitae convallis libero accumsan. Praesent semper lacus in tellus eleifend, et tristique lorem egestas.</p>
            <p>Praesent ut nisi massa. Nam aliquam sapien volutpat mauris suscipit facilisis. Ut accumsan lorem vel eleifend ullamcorper. Nulla at lobortis purus. Praesent viverra in velit a aliquet. In in vulputate massa. Integer ac ligula a risus iaculis pharetra imperdiet sit amet lectus. Proin vestibulum efficitur imperdiet. Suspendisse ac hendrerit ante.</p>
            <p>Aenean eu ipsum eros. Aenean faucibus sollicitudin mi, vel ullamcorper nisi porttitor a. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris facilisis eu neque id dignissim. Pellentesque nunc enim, feugiat ac orci vel, bibendum tincidunt sem. Vivamus placerat finibus ultricies. Curabitur ac fringilla diam.</p>
            <p>Integer mi nibh, accumsan fringilla consectetur eu, scelerisque nec ipsum. Nullam in bibendum risus. Integer fringilla enim ac diam sollicitudin, eget elementum odio accumsan. Aliquam efficitur congue ante volutpat lacinia. Nam et ante eu arcu bibendum mollis. Morbi elementum mauris tristique ullamcorper dictum. Vestibulum ultrices, nibh vel tristique lacinia, massa orci feugiat nisi, nec mattis libero sem sit amet sem. Curabitur in leo quis sapien porta blandit sit amet sed felis. Proin et diam nisi. Sed quis sapien quis lectus molestie imperdiet.</p>
            <p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam euismod arcu molestie, congue felis non, placerat lacus. Proin semper nisi non posuere porttitor. Donec turpis ipsum, tincidunt in pellentesque in, accumsan at ipsum. Fusce rhoncus auctor sem sed fringilla. Sed sodales lorem rhoncus nunc blandit vestibulum. Vestibulum convallis egestas maximus. Donec porta velit ipsum, porttitor condimentum ipsum cursus nec. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In volutpat gravida iaculis. In porttitor mattis eros, et feugiat lectus pulvinar ut. Vestibulum vel libero at justo posuere tristique et in mauris. Duis condimentum lacinia luctus. Mauris ut cursus lacus, pellentesque efficitur metus. Nunc gravida, ex cursus commodo hendrerit, arcu metus scelerisque ligula, eu lacinia felis massa blandit diam. Pellentesque ac consequat est.</p>
            <p>Cras volutpat vitae ipsum non molestie. Aliquam id risus quam. Aenean malesuada dui sed est suscipit varius. Morbi maximus diam luctus tempus mattis. In sit amet pulvinar eros, non imperdiet neque. Nullam suscipit tortor risus, pellentesque molestie tortor pharetra vel. Proin quis malesuada lacus. Sed pharetra scelerisque leo. Praesent accumsan at ipsum eu rutrum. Nam fermentum velit quis arcu ullamcorper maximus. Pellentesque blandit vehicula libero, eget sagittis est imperdiet et. Curabitur nisl eros, consequat vel tellus vehicula, pulvinar porta tellus.</p>
            <p>Integer porttitor placerat fringilla. Proin eleifend in nulla in commodo. Etiam a dictum dui. Aliquam faucibus massa in lacinia fermentum. Nunc placerat condimentum tortor, sit amet varius mauris pretium quis. In non arcu dolor. Praesent venenatis sed sem eleifend consectetur. In ex mi, vestibulum non interdum et, luctus vel sem. Duis eu diam a tellus bibendum elementum.</p>
            <p>Praesent condimentum sem eget magna consequat, eget gravida libero elementum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a posuere metus. Nullam tellus justo, venenatis sit amet arcu eu, venenatis vulputate neque. Etiam vestibulum orci quis mauris lacinia, et blandit arcu imperdiet. Vestibulum aliquam scelerisque justo, tincidunt congue orci convallis a. Ut facilisis arcu non orci interdum, sit amet facilisis mi consequat. Cras sed venenatis erat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc pharetra a sapien non ultrices. Donec finibus nulla quis purus ullamcorper, sit amet accumsan sem blandit. Ut tempus justo quis nulla viverra iaculis. In placerat turpis sit amet quam tincidunt, eget lobortis dui imperdiet. Fusce a malesuada ligula, et dapibus dolor. Maecenas euismod dui nec mauris fermentum fringilla.</p>
            <p>Mauris dui lectus, luctus et auctor mollis, luctus fringilla dui. Duis pharetra massa id arcu imperdiet mollis. Nam ornare efficitur gravida. Sed ultrices nibh nisi, ut maximus purus aliquam et. In dignissim ut tortor nec tincidunt. Sed tellus arcu, posuere vitae nulla eu, pellentesque feugiat mi. Phasellus lectus enim, tincidunt nec dui eu, congue egestas augue.</p>
            <p>Praesent eget purus suscipit, placerat purus ac, lacinia metus. Curabitur placerat facilisis augue, non sagittis ipsum dictum et. Mauris luctus et risus vel laoreet. Maecenas tempor ipsum a massa gravida auctor. Nunc nec massa sed urna aliquet posuere ut nec augue. Integer lacus nisi, ultricies at neque id, vestibulum suscipit lorem. Vestibulum efficitur arcu vitae magna bibendum gravida. Ut purus lorem, vestibulum quis ipsum eu, efficitur suscipit ligula. Sed nec urna libero. Pellentesque ullamcorper turpis non ullamcorper pulvinar. Nullam vestibulum, dui a congue venenatis, nibh sem tempus urna, non dapibus ligula orci et diam. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus facilisis lobortis est, eget convallis est cursus at. Ut id ullamcorper dolor.</p>
            <p>Sed nisl lorem, sodales sed pretium et, consectetur sollicitudin mi. Etiam sed urna tempor, fermentum sapien ut, euismod nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus at ipsum ut odio convallis molestie. Integer ultricies ornare leo ac tempus. Mauris accumsan bibendum dapibus. Integer quis nunc vitae mauris eleifend dictum ut non velit. Aliquam non lacus ut tellus fringilla auctor. Donec et pellentesque dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum semper maximus lacus, a hendrerit erat. Quisque felis magna, tincidunt eu enim non, consequat pharetra nunc. Pellentesque sodales nulla eu facilisis venenatis. Vestibulum quis tortor quis sapien tincidunt aliquam nec mattis enim.</p>
            <p>Ut eget sagittis erat. Fusce euismod volutpat diam, non semper lorem congue accumsan. Proin malesuada erat id sodales scelerisque. Aliquam non quam ut magna rutrum commodo. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer a sem eu metus consectetur malesuada rutrum non magna.</p>
         </article>
         <aside>
            <p>Praesent ut nisi massa. Nam aliquam sapien volutpat mauris suscipit facilisis. Ut accumsan lorem vel eleifend ullamcorper. Nulla at lobortis purus. Praesent viverra in velit a aliquet. In in vulputate massa. Integer ac ligula a risus iaculis pharetra imperdiet sit amet lectus. Proin vestibulum efficitur imperdiet. Suspendisse ac hendrerit ante.</p>
         </aside>
         <footer>
            <p class="accent">Philip Blaine, Proprietor</p>
            <p>45 Marsh Grass Ln. &bull; Marble, MN 55764 &bull; (218) 555-5253</p>
         </footer>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

A white space appears above where the header should go, which should remain fixed at the top and follow as you scroll without overlap at the beginning. Then the "LR" is not applying any ruling at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `top: 0;` to your header in CSS. It should look like this:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 640px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    /*z-index: -1*/
    top: 0;
}
```

Now you can see that the container has slipped a little. Therefore you could not give the container `top: 6.2em;` but approx. `top: 7.5em;`. At the end it should look like this:

```
.container {
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: beige;
    position: relative;
    top: 6.2em;
}
```

### Here is the full code:

```css
/* 
   Lakeland Reeds Bed and Breakfast style sheet 
   Filename: styles.css

   Author:  
   Date:    
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit D, Lessons
 */

/* reset styles */
article, body, div, footer, header, h1, h2, p {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* body and page container */
.container {
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: beige;
    position: relative;
    top: 7.5em;
}

/* headings */
header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 640px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    /*z-index: -1*/
    top: 0;
}
h1 {
    padding: 0.4em;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
}

p.logo {
    padding: 0.2em;
    border: 2px solid beige;
    color: goldenrod;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 2em;
}

/* main content */
article {
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
    top: 6.2em;
}

article p {
    padding: 0 1em 1em;
}

/* sidebar */
aside {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 1em 0;
    background-color: goldenrod;
}

aside p {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    padding:  0.4em 0;
    margin: 0 0.6em;
}

/* footer section */
footer {
    padding: 0.6em;
    color: white;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    text-align: center;
    clear: right;
}
footer p {
    margin:  0.4em;
}

footer p.accent {
    color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Lakeland Reeds Bed &amp; Breakfast - Test Page</title>
      <!-- 
         Lakeland Reeds Bed & Breakfast test page
         Filename: longpage.html

         Author:  
         Date:    
         HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit D, Lessons
      -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script src="modernizr.custom.62074.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <header>
            <h1>Lakeland Reeds<br>Bed &amp; Breakfast</h1>
            <p class=”logo”>&#8466;&#8475;</p>
         </header>
         <article>
            <h2>Test Page</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam viverra ullamcorper ultrices. Morbi egestas elementum ligula, eget congue elit pulvinar placerat. Curabitur dictum, velit et iaculis mattis, felis ante sodales lectus, consectetur convallis enim urna ut libero. Suspendisse placerat dignissim quam, et consequat ligula. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur id dolor ut nulla sodales lobortis in ac dolor. Maecenas bibendum eleifend lacus, maximus dignissim mi fermentum quis. Suspendisse sagittis tincidunt pellentesque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla nunc velit, molestie nec metus vel, dictum rutrum est. Aliquam volutpat ex massa, tempus eleifend nisl eleifend sed. Fusce egestas cursus felis in fermentum. Mauris facilisis feugiat pellentesque. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec feugiat erat nec sapien tincidunt congue. Etiam urna libero, aliquet ut neque a, vulputate fermentum velit.</p>
            <p>Nullam vel enim luctus, imperdiet neque et, aliquet turpis. Morbi a rhoncus metus. Nulla facilisi. Nunc tincidunt vel eros id laoreet. Fusce id nibh rhoncus, porta nulla nec, euismod ligula. Phasellus bibendum mi lectus. Donec a egestas mauris.</p>
            <p>Curabitur et sapien consequat, varius diam in, viverra massa. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum facilisis urna elit, vel malesuada mauris pulvinar vitae. In ultrices tortor nisl, et faucibus ex dignissim non. Vivamus eget risus tempus, rutrum ipsum sit amet, gravida mi. Vestibulum et lobortis sem. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
            <p>Donec ultricies risus quis metus cursus, in feugiat quam ultricies. Nullam sit amet enim in tellus molestie sodales et et leo. Duis pulvinar venenatis consequat. Aenean facilisis arcu libero, a auctor odio feugiat at. Donec sagittis sollicitudin maximus. Maecenas elementum, lectus vitae fringilla tempus, mi nibh faucibus sapien, in fermentum dui massa vel dui. Nullam sed ligula scelerisque, viverra quam sit amet, bibendum libero. Duis at fermentum dolor. Phasellus non dictum nulla. Morbi a semper nibh. Vivamus ullamcorper purus ac nisi consectetur bibendum. Nulla varius sodales tempor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur imperdiet neque nec purus pellentesque, vitae convallis libero accumsan. Praesent semper lacus in tellus eleifend, et tristique lorem egestas.</p>
            <p>Praesent ut nisi massa. Nam aliquam sapien volutpat mauris suscipit facilisis. Ut accumsan lorem vel eleifend ullamcorper. Nulla at lobortis purus. Praesent viverra in velit a aliquet. In in vulputate massa. Integer ac ligula a risus iaculis pharetra imperdiet sit amet lectus. Proin vestibulum efficitur imperdiet. Suspendisse ac hendrerit ante.</p>
            <p>Aenean eu ipsum eros. Aenean faucibus sollicitudin mi, vel ullamcorper nisi porttitor a. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris facilisis eu neque id dignissim. Pellentesque nunc enim, feugiat ac orci vel, bibendum tincidunt sem. Vivamus placerat finibus ultricies. Curabitur ac fringilla diam.</p>
            <p>Integer mi nibh, accumsan fringilla consectetur eu, scelerisque nec ipsum. Nullam in bibendum risus. Integer fringilla enim ac diam sollicitudin, eget elementum odio accumsan. Aliquam efficitur congue ante volutpat lacinia. Nam et ante eu arcu bibendum mollis. Morbi elementum mauris tristique ullamcorper dictum. Vestibulum ultrices, nibh vel tristique lacinia, massa orci feugiat nisi, nec mattis libero sem sit amet sem. Curabitur in leo quis sapien porta blandit sit amet sed felis. Proin et diam nisi. Sed quis sapien quis lectus molestie imperdiet.</p>
            <p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam euismod arcu molestie, congue felis non, placerat lacus. Proin semper nisi non posuere porttitor. Donec turpis ipsum, tincidunt in pellentesque in, accumsan at ipsum. Fusce rhoncus auctor sem sed fringilla. Sed sodales lorem rhoncus nunc blandit vestibulum. Vestibulum convallis egestas maximus. Donec porta velit ipsum, porttitor condimentum ipsum cursus nec. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In volutpat gravida iaculis. In porttitor mattis eros, et feugiat lectus pulvinar ut. Vestibulum vel libero at justo posuere tristique et in mauris. Duis condimentum lacinia luctus. Mauris ut cursus lacus, pellentesque efficitur metus. Nunc gravida, ex cursus commodo hendrerit, arcu metus scelerisque ligula, eu lacinia felis massa blandit diam. Pellentesque ac consequat est.</p>
            <p>Cras volutpat vitae ipsum non molestie. Aliquam id risus quam. Aenean malesuada dui sed est suscipit varius. Morbi maximus diam luctus tempus mattis. In sit amet pulvinar eros, non imperdiet neque. Nullam suscipit tortor risus, pellentesque molestie tortor pharetra vel. Proin quis malesuada lacus. Sed pharetra scelerisque leo. Praesent accumsan at ipsum eu rutrum. Nam fermentum velit quis arcu ullamcorper maximus. Pellentesque blandit vehicula libero, eget sagittis est imperdiet et. Curabitur nisl eros, consequat vel tellus vehicula, pulvinar porta tellus.</p>
            <p>Integer porttitor placerat fringilla. Proin eleifend in nulla in commodo. Etiam a dictum dui. Aliquam faucibus massa in lacinia fermentum. Nunc placerat condimentum tortor, sit amet varius mauris pretium quis. In non arcu dolor. Praesent venenatis sed sem eleifend consectetur. In ex mi, vestibulum non interdum et, luctus vel sem. Duis eu diam a tellus bibendum elementum.</p>
            <p>Praesent condimentum sem eget magna consequat, eget gravida libero elementum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a posuere metus. Nullam tellus justo, venenatis sit amet arcu eu, venenatis vulputate neque. Etiam vestibulum orci quis mauris lacinia, et blandit arcu imperdiet. Vestibulum aliquam scelerisque justo, tincidunt congue orci convallis a. Ut facilisis arcu non orci interdum, sit amet facilisis mi consequat. Cras sed venenatis erat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc pharetra a sapien non ultrices. Donec finibus nulla quis purus ullamcorper, sit amet accumsan sem blandit. Ut tempus justo quis nulla viverra iaculis. In placerat turpis sit amet quam tincidunt, eget lobortis dui imperdiet. Fusce a malesuada ligula, et dapibus dolor. Maecenas euismod dui nec mauris fermentum fringilla.</p>
            <p>Mauris dui lectus, luctus et auctor mollis, luctus fringilla dui. Duis pharetra massa id arcu imperdiet mollis. Nam ornare efficitur gravida. Sed ultrices nibh nisi, ut maximus purus aliquam et. In dignissim ut tortor nec tincidunt. Sed tellus arcu, posuere vitae nulla eu, pellentesque feugiat mi. Phasellus lectus enim, tincidunt nec dui eu, congue egestas augue.</p>
            <p>Praesent eget purus suscipit, placerat purus ac, lacinia metus. Curabitur placerat facilisis augue, non sagittis ipsum dictum et. Mauris luctus et risus vel laoreet. Maecenas tempor ipsum a massa gravida auctor. Nunc nec massa sed urna aliquet posuere ut nec augue. Integer lacus nisi, ultricies at neque id, vestibulum suscipit lorem. Vestibulum efficitur arcu vitae magna bibendum gravida. Ut purus lorem, vestibulum quis ipsum eu, efficitur suscipit ligula. Sed nec urna libero. Pellentesque ullamcorper turpis non ullamcorper pulvinar. Nullam vestibulum, dui a congue venenatis, nibh sem tempus urna, non dapibus ligula orci et diam. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus facilisis lobortis est, eget convallis est cursus at. Ut id ullamcorper dolor.</p>
            <p>Sed nisl lorem, sodales sed pretium et, consectetur sollicitudin mi. Etiam sed urna tempor, fermentum sapien ut, euismod nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus at ipsum ut odio convallis molestie. Integer ultricies ornare leo ac tempus. Mauris accumsan bibendum dapibus. Integer quis nunc vitae mauris eleifend dictum ut non velit. Aliquam non lacus ut tellus fringilla auctor. Donec et pellentesque dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum semper maximus lacus, a hendrerit erat. Quisque felis magna, tincidunt eu enim non, consequat pharetra nunc. Pellentesque sodales nulla eu facilisis venenatis. Vestibulum quis tortor quis sapien tincidunt aliquam nec mattis enim.</p>
            <p>Ut eget sagittis erat. Fusce euismod volutpat diam, non semper lorem congue accumsan. Proin malesuada erat id sodales scelerisque. Aliquam non quam ut magna rutrum commodo. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer a sem eu metus consectetur malesuada rutrum non magna.</p>
         </article>
         <aside>
            <p>Praesent ut nisi massa. Nam aliquam sapien volutpat mauris suscipit facilisis. Ut accumsan lorem vel eleifend ullamcorper. Nulla at lobortis purus. Praesent viverra in velit a aliquet. In in vulputate massa. Integer ac ligula a risus iaculis pharetra imperdiet sit amet lectus. Proin vestibulum efficitur imperdiet. Suspendisse ac hendrerit ante.</p>
         </aside>
         <footer>
            <p class="accent">Philip Blaine, Proprietor</p>
            <p>45 Marsh Grass Ln. &bull; Marble, MN 55764 &bull; (218) 555-5253</p>
         </footer>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. I just wanted to make a comment: If you click on the tick at the top left of the question, you can show other people with the same problem that it can be solved this way. I just wanted to say it :)